# How to use CIVIHR for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, installation, civihr

I am working on CIVI CRM on wordpress. I need to make HR module in CIVI CRM. Can anyone tell me how to integrate CIVIHR extension in CIVI CRM.?

Answer (score 1):

There are installation instructions on the [CiviHR github page](https://github.com/civicrm/civihr/blob/staging/doc/INSTALL.md).

Answer (score 1):

The installation instructions reference Drush - the Drupal command line tool. I would inquire of the developer before even trying this on WordPress.

Create a Github account and ask the question there as any issue.